# How to adjust tab completion in Sublime Text 2

Tags: sublime-text-2, tab-completion

Is there a way to "complete completion within completion"? Example:

Completions:

```
'fra' => '\frac{$1}{$0}'
'bf' => '\mathbf{$0}'
```

I do `fra<tab>bf<tab>` and want to have `\frac{\mathbf{***}}{}`, not `\frac{bf}{***}` where `***` is the cursor.

Comment: Pressing `Escape` between the first and second tab would be a possible workaround to cancel the first completion's chain of insert locations.

Comment: [Related (unanswered) topic on the Sublime forums](http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=9281).

Comment: @DanielBeck: That unfortunately conflicts with exiting the insert mode in Vintage.

Comment: Open up the default key binding file and search for `clear_fields`. This is the command that cancels the chain of fields in snippets. Just bind that to any key combination (and use the same context) in your user key bindings file.

Comment: Alternatively, bind `next_field` to a different key combination and press that instead. The `Tab` key is really overloaded...

Comment: You could also change Vintage's `Default.sublime-keymap` to require an additional `{ "key": "has_next_field", "operator": "equal", "operand": false }` in its context for `exit_insert_mode`. (Untested though).

Answer (score 0):

At least part of the answer is setting `"auto_complete_with_fields": true` in your settings file.

That will make it trigger the completion instead of skipping to the next tab stop.